# Libgdx opacity partial error

Tags: java, libgdx, android

[image]
[image]

My model must support transfer textures but I can't do this using mesh + modelBuilder.part

Opacity is tested correctly on only half of the model.

```
BlendingAttribute blendingAttribute = new BlendingAttribute();
        blendingAttribute.opacity = 1.0f;
        
        modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin(); 
        modelBuilder.part("minecraft:loading_model", mesh, 4, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(atlas), blendingAttribute));
        modelInstance = new ModelInstance(modelBuilder.end());
```

Comment: It looks like you should show us the relevant code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Really .. sorry I went down

Comment: Looks like you're using alpha blending, without disabling z writes. You more likely want to use alpha testing, so that you abort the transparent fragments before they write to the depth buffer and block the next quad from drawing there.

Comment: Yes, the minecraft oak tree should be composed of two planes with transparent pixels

Comment: I found the solution in a badlogic forum. modelInstance.materials.get(0).set(FloatAttribute.createAlphaTest(0.95f));

Comment: Sounds like you should post that as an Answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in a badlogic forum.

This:

```
modelBuilder.part("minecraft:loading_model", mesh, 4, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(atlas), blendingAttribute, FloatAttribute.createAlphaTest(0.95f)));
```

Or this:

```
modelInstance.materials.get(0).set(FloatAttribute.createAlphaTest(0.95f));
```

[image]